# *ngIf won't open a template

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a .html file to show some values. I add a condition with "*ngIf" inside my tag to find a value that ends with "Rechercher ...". Perhaps I can't find how to make it work. 
I try several things and now I just have a boolean with a value at true to find if I can switch between my template but he still won't open one of them.

**Original (working)**

```html
<datalist id="{{row.LISTID}}">
    <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let i of tableEquipmentDataTmp[row.LISTID]" value="{{i.OBJECTID}}"> {{i.OBJECTID}}
    </option>
</datalist>
```

**Changes (not working)**

```html
<datalist id="{{row.LISTID}}">
    <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
    <div *ngFor="let i of tableObjectDataTmp[row.LISTID]">
        <ng-template *ngIf="isTrue else disabled_lock">
            <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}">{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #disabled_lock>
            <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}" disabled>{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</datalist>
```

**ts** (edit)

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    isTrue = true;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.isTrue = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template), an `ngTemplate` cannot be displayed by itself; it must be displayed by a structural directive. By using the `*ngIf` [shorthand syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#shorthand-syntax) in your markup, you end up with this equivalent markup:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isTrue" [ngIfElse]="disabled_lock">
  <ng-template>
    <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}">{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
  </ng-template>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #disabled_lock>
  <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}" disabled>{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
</ng-template>
```

The outer `ngTemplate` of the `ngIf` part is appropriately controlled by the `ngIf` directive but the inner `ngTemplate` has no structural directive applied to it. As a result, it is never displayed.

One possible solution is to use the explicit `ngIf` notation, as suggested in [SoCo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59896376/1009922). Another solution is to apply the `*ngIf` directive to the `option` element:

```
<option *ngIf="isTrue else disabled_lock" value="{{i.OBJECTID}}">{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
<ng-template #disabled_lock>
  <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}" disabled>{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
</ng-template>
```

In cases where the first `ngTemplate` would contain several elements, you could replace it with an `ng‑container`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isTrue else disabled_lock">
  <option value="value1">Caption 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Caption 2</option>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #disabled_lock>
  <option value="value3" disabled>Caption 3</option>
</ng-template>
```

You can experiment with the following stackblitz examples: [the first one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4sv1kb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is similar to your current code while [the second one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhepee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) applies the `*ngIf` directive to an HTML element instead of an `ngTemplate`.

---

All that being said, your code example doesn't really need an `ngIf` structural directive since the two parts differ only by the `disabled` property. You could just bind that property:

```
<option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}" [disabled]="!isTrue">{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
```

Comment: Alternatively the first ng-template could be replaced by ng-container.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - I had made that suggestion earlier in my answer but I removed it since it does not provide any benefit in this specific case. By the way, I am surprised that, in the other two answers, the one that works has been downvoted and the one that doesn't has been upvoted.

Comment: Well the other answer got an upvote from me by accident, but it's "locked" so I can't remove it, so that one's partially my fault. ;) I think mentioning the ng-container would be useful to mention for more complex cases, though.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - I put back the `ng-container` solution. Thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you're checking `isTrue`, but not `i.isTrue`.

```html
<datalist id="{{row.LISTID}}">
    <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
    <div *ngFor="let i of tableObjectDataTmp[row.LISTID]">
        <ng-template *ngIf="i.isTrue else disabled_lock">
            <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}">{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #disabled_lock>
            <option value="{{i.OBJECTID}}" disabled>{{i.OBJECTID}}</option>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</datalist>
```

Comment: isTrue is defined in my .ts. I don't think. I don’t think that’s it.

Comment: Can you show your .ts file then? .ts might not be initialized by the time angular tries to render template.

Comment: My component is huge and I use some sensitive data at my work. 
You can see how I define and set my value "isTrue" in the snippet #edit.

Comment: What if you replace `ng-template` with `ng-container`?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `<ng-template>` `*ngIf` syntax from

```
<ng-template *ngIf="isTrue else disabled_lock">
```

to

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isTrue" [ngIfElse]="disabled_lock">
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6xhvx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is a small demo demonstrating how it works.

You can read more about the `*ngIf` directive [here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then#standard-ngif-in-angular)

Comment: This answer does work. I don't know why someone downvoted it.